# Getting P5js AudioIn to MediaStream Object

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api, p5.js, mediastream

I'm trying to merge Audio & Video Streams. I'm using `p5.js` and am unable to figure out how to get a mediastream object from `P5.js 's AudioIn Function`?

**Below is the code snippet :**

```
audioRecorder = new p5.SoundRecorder();
audioRecorder.setInput(voiceStream);
voiceStream.start();
let ctx = new AudioContext();
let sourceNode2 = ctx.createMediaStreamSource(voiceStream);
let dest = ctx.createMediaStreamDestination();
//... connecting stream to dest code goes here
let audioTrack = dest.stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
```